# Memory issue with [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing application which required image caching. For doing this, I am using JMImageCache library. It is work fine for caching. But It can not release memory occupied by
following line.

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile]
```

Here, is function which content code for cache image from disk.

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromDiskForURL:(NSString *)url {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cachePathForURL(url) options:0 error:NULL];
    UIImage *i = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
    data = nil;
    [data release];
    return i;
}
```

I have check it with instruments and it alloc 2.34 MB each time.

Comment: You are in the serious need of 1. Getting a grasp on the concept of 'sequences' (something very basic and fundamental in programming). 2. **reading a good Objective-C tutorial.** 3. Reading Apple's memory management guide and learning all the (not-only-naming) conventions. You had 2 very serious errors in 7 lines of code. I might not want to install any of your apps because I fear that they would eventually take my device down...

Comment: @H2CO3 Tutorials suck.... books are the good stuff. I remember wasting 3 weeks on YouTube tutorials, thinking WHAT ARE THOSE ASTERIKS FOR !?

Comment: @RohanKapur I didn't mean YouTube 'tutorials'. Those are very low-quality for sure. Written stuff is much better.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah true, I always recognize 'tutorials' as video tutorials, don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

```
data = nil;
[data release];
```

Why do you expect this at all to work? Why should this release the original data? You're sending the `release` message to `nil`, which is a no-op.

Furthermore, if you don't create the object using `alloc` or `copy`, then it's autoreleased. That means if you release it once more, it will be overreleased and most likely your app is going to crash. What you need is:

One. Wrap the method call in an explicit autorelease pool:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromDiskForURL:(NSString *)url
{
    UIImage *i;
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cachePathForURL(url) options:0 error:NULL];
        i = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    }
    return [i autorelease];
}
```

Two, alloc-init or manually release the data object:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromDiskForURL:(NSString *)url
{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:cachePathForURL(url) options:0 error:NULL];
    UIImage *i = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
    [data release];
    return i;
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks for your answer, I try both of above. In first option, i bring return statement into "@autoreleasepool", but it give me BadExcess when using this image.

Comment: second option doesn't release memory.

Comment: @PlayCool 'I bring return statement to autoreleasepool' - Why do you think I didn't? 'cause it would crash. The second one should release the memory - unless the data is retained by the image (which is quite possible, indeed). Don't try to guess internals of the OS. The way I've shown you is **right.**

Comment: @H2CO3 If i take 'return i' into autoreleasepool it give me compile time error.

Comment: @PlayCool But didn't you read neither my answer nor my comment? ***DO NOT*** put the `return` statement inside the autorelease pool.

Comment: @H2CO3 ok i removed return from autorelease pool

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23557/discussion-between-play-cool-and-h2co3)

Comment: @H2CO3 - It won't compile with the return outside the autorelease pool block. `i` is not in scope when you return it autoreleased. But yes, it'll break if you return inside there. You need to declare `i` before the autorelease pool scope.

Answer (score 1):

alter the sequence nil and release

```
[data release];
data = nil;
```

and for clearing the cache use following delegate methods

```
[[JMImageCache sharedCache] removeAllObjects];
[[JMImageCache sharedCache] removeImageForURL:@"http://dundermifflin.com/i/MichaelScott.png"];
```

read the read me file of library 
https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache/blob/master/README.markdown

Comment: If you're executing this, it will crash. This is overreleasing.

Comment: I think H2CO3 answer is much better than me and Play cool is not originally allocating the memory, it is a shallow copy of the memory. it looks original allocated memory is somewhere else.

Comment: @Playcool: go to https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache/blob/master/README.markdownand download the zip, and open the JMImageCacheDemo.xcodeproj in Xcode.
now open the DemoViewController.m file and go to the table delegate funtion DidselectRowAtIndexPath
now add this line
[[JMImageCache sharedCache] removeAllObjects];
and run the project..... 
once it will take time to load all images, after that it all images will be visible. then select any row selecting any row will clear data from cache and now few item will reload.
test it

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do cannot work due to the way how UIImage uses a data you pass it. The data object is retained by the image, or more precisely by a CGImageSource that the UIImage has internally. From this data it is able to decompress and create the image any time. There is an option on CGImageSource to also keep around the decompressed data, but UIImage does not use that because it optimized for small UI graphics.

One thing that you can do to alleviate memory pressure is to not load the entire NSData into memory, but to memory-map it instead. This makes creation or recreation of the image a tad slower, but the created NSData object is very small in comparison.

Comment: Please look at the documentwtion for NSData.