# Memory leak at JMImagecache

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am developing app which download & display images into grid style.

I use following code for load image into my custom view.

```
MyView *myview = (MyView *)[self.imageListingScrollView viewWithTag:100+counter1];
        myview.imgPhoto.image = [[JMImageCache sharedCache] imageForURL:myview.imageURL delegate:self];
        myview.imageURL = nil;
```

It works fine. but it create memory issue.For finding memory issue i used "Instruments". It give me memory leak at

```
UIImage *i = [self imageFromDiskForURL:url];
```

into JMImageCache.m file into following methods

```
- (UIImage *) imageForURL:(NSString *)url delegate:(id<JMImageCacheDelegate>)d {
if(!url) {
    return nil;
}

id returner = [super objectForKey:url];

if(returner) {
    return returner;
} else {
    UIImage *i = [self imageFromDiskForURL:url];
    if(i) {
        [d imageComeFromDisk:url image:i];
        [self setImage:i forURL:url];
        return i;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSError *error =nil;
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"error: %@",[error description]);
        }
        UIImage *i = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];

        NSString* cachePath = cachePathForURL(url);
        NSInvocation* writeInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(writeData:toPath:)]];
        [writeInvocation setTarget:self];
        [writeInvocation setSelector:@selector(writeData:toPath:)];
        [writeInvocation setArgument:&data atIndex:2];
        [writeInvocation setArgument:&cachePath atIndex:3];
        NSLog(@"%@",cachePath);
        data = nil;
        [self performDiskWriteOperation:writeInvocation];
        [self setImage:i forURL:url];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(d) {
                if([d respondsToSelector:@selector(cache:didDownloadImage:forURL:)]) {
                    if(i==nil){
                        NSLog(@"image not get.");
                    }
                    [d cache:self didDownloadImage:i forURL:url];
                }
            }
        });
    });

    return nil;
}
```

}

It create memory upto 150 MB. Please give me suggestion to reduce this memory issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe is the same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577612/memory-issue-with-nsdata-datawithcontentsoffile

Comment: Yes It is just like similar.but i did not get working answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use @autoreleasepool while creating the UIImage instance like this even your application is ARC enabled to avoid memory leaks.

```
@autoreleasepool{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSError *error =nil;
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"error: %@",[error description]);
        }
        UIImage *i = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];

        NSString* cachePath = cachePathForURL(url);
        NSInvocation* writeInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(writeData:toPath:)]];
        [writeInvocation setTarget:self];
        [writeInvocation setSelector:@selector(writeData:toPath:)];
        [writeInvocation setArgument:&data atIndex:2];
        [writeInvocation setArgument:&cachePath atIndex:3];
        NSLog(@"%@",cachePath);
        data = nil;
        [self performDiskWriteOperation:writeInvocation];
        [self setImage:i forURL:url];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(d) {
                if([d respondsToSelector:@selector(cache:didDownloadImage:forURL:)]) {
                    if(i==nil){
                        NSLog(@"image not get.");
                    }
                    [d cache:self didDownloadImage:i forURL:url];
                }
            }
        });
    });

    return nil;

}
```